# How does the Sportsmanship badge work?

Tags: discussion, voting, badges

So, the [sportsmanship](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/805/sportsmanship) badge seems pretty cut and <del>dry</del>[dried](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cut-and-dried).

> Up voted 100 answers on questions where an answer of yours has a positive score.

The wording seems to suggest that your answer must already have an upvote in order for your upvotes on other answers to count.

Is this correct?

If I upvote an answer, and later my own answer receives an upvote, will the upvote I previously issued count toward badge progress? (I'd assume not)

If not, what if I were to undo and subsequently redo my upvote? (I'd assume it would count)

---

Note: I'm only asking for curiosity's sake. I'm not planning on undoing and redoing any votes for this badge.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> If I upvote an answer, and later my own answer receives an upvote, will the upvote I previously issued count toward badge progress?

Yes, it will. There's no requirement that the votes come in at any particular time - just that they still exist when the badge eligibility is calculated.

#### See also: [Voting for competing answers (Sportsmanship badge)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68137/voting-for-competing-answers-sportsmanship-badge/68156#68156)

> After intense public outcry, we've removed the restriction that your upvotes on competing answers must occur after your answer.

Comment: Oh goodie, a sportsmanship opportunity! :-)

Comment: Behold the power of intense public outcry!

Answer (score 27):

*Any* competing answer you up-voted, where your answer has a positive score, counts.

So yes, your answer must have at least one up-vote. No, it doesn't matter when you get that up-vote.

Once upon a time, there *was* a restriction on when *you* cast *your* vote on the competing answer, but that restriction was removed. See [Modify the "competing answer" rule to ignore when votes were cast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69438/modify-the-competing-answer-rule-to-ignore-when-votes-were-cast)

So, the way it works now is that periodically a script queries for all users that have upvoted at least 100 answers that are not their own on questions they have an answer for with a positive score, and who do not yet have the badge. It then hands out the badges to those users. Vote timelines are not taken into account.