# A better understanding of the Sportmanship badge

Tags: support, badges, upvotes

I have been looking at the badges lately and I was having some doubts on how to get the Sportsmanship badge.

- If I upvoted before I get upvoted, does my old vote count?
- What if my answer is marked correct, but it has 0 up votes because that user did not had the reputation at the time to up vote? Would the other votes you made on those questions count for the 100 Sportmanship upvotes?

Comment: Why would you downvote a legitimate question someone has about how the site works? Anyway, I don't believe it matters when the vote happens. No, scoring is only up/down votes. Accepts don't count towards the score

Comment: [0 is not a positive score](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186441/does-the-positive-score-include-zero-in-stack-overflow), therefore your accepted answer with a score of 0 wouldn't count.

Comment: [Why does the Sportsmanship badge not take into account your own 0 score answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/241914/259693) -- my question on MSE.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Here are the rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/175248) for the Sportsmanship badge:

> - Cast 100 upvotes on competing answers
>
>   - If you answer a question and earn a score of at least one, all other answers to that question are considered "competing answers"
>   - <strike>Upvotes you cast before you post your own answer do not count</strike>
>   - Deleted posts do not count
>   - Retracted votes do not count

So, to answer your questions:

- Yes; [upvotes you cast before your answer was upvoted would count](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275270/1079354), and
- No, since upvotes are not the same as accepted answers.

Comment: Unless I'm reading something wrong, either [this post is outdated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275268/how-does-the-sportsmanship-badge-work) or the help center is

Comment: Curious indeed. Not sure who I can trust anymore. *"If I upvoted before I get upvoted, does my old vote count?"* the OP isn't asking about when the answer is given but when the votes arrive.

Comment: Okay, so it was less of their being conflicting information, and more of me misreading the question.  I've since corrected it.